# React helmet async returns empty tags on server with Apollo client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client, server-side-rendering, react-helmet

On the server I'm trying to get Helmet meta and title tags from nested child components, using `react-helmet-async` because `react-helmet` was not working. But this does not seem to be working either, I always get an empty title tag, with no meta tags returned (they're all set in child components)

```
const helmetContext = {};
    const app = (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <HelmetProvider context={helmetContext}>
          <Router location={req.url} context={staticContext}>
            <CookiesProvider cookies={req.universalCookies}>
                <App />
            </CookiesProvider>
          </Router>
        </HelmetProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );

//Traverses Component tree and executes all queries
getDataFromTree(app).then(() => {
  const content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(app);
  const state = client.extract();
  const { helmet } = helmetContext;   // This is always empty
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Html content={content} helmet={helmet} assets={assets} state={state} initData={initData}/>,
  );

  res.status(200);
  res.send(`<!doctype html>${html}`);
  res.end();

}).catch(e => {
  console.error('RENDERING ERROR:', e); 
  res.status(500);
  console.log(e.stack);
  res.end(
    `An error occurred.:\n\n${
      e.stack
    }`
  );
});`
```

Any help on how I can get access to nested Helmet tags from child components. I'm wrapping the app on the client with `HelmetProvider` as well. It works perfectly fine on the client, but on the server it's not picking any tags from nested components. I'm not streaming the response, it's a simple SSR set up. This kinda defeats the purpose of setting up SSR so I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: This turned out to be due an unrelated issue of the component not getting rendered at all. `react-helmet-async` works fine on pages that load content correctly.